# Using multiple threads with tornado PeriodicCallback

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

I have an application that needs 3 periodic callbacks
(Only one of them really interacts with the ioloop because it pushes data to the via the websocket)

```
def make_app():
  return tornado.web.Application([
                (r"/websocket", WebsocketHandler),
                (r"/getData", DataRequestHandler),
  ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback=calculator1, callback_time=500).start()
  tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback=calculator2, callback_time=1000).start()
  tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback=push, callback_time=1000).start()
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I find that all of this is run in the main thread
The problem is then that because `calculator2` could take more that 500ms to run, it blocks the thread and `calculator1` may not run at the next 500ms because thread was blocked

How do I properly schedule `calculator1` and `calculator2` periodic functions in different threads other than the main thread?

I am not certain how to make the functions run in different threads other than the ioloop thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tornado's [`run_in_executor()`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor) method to run blocking tasks in separate threads.

You'll need to create another function to run periodically which will execute the actual `calculator1` function in another thread.

```
# create a thread pool
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)


def calculator1_runner():
    """This function is for calling the calculator1 function"""
    IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(executor, calculator1) 


# Register the runner function for periodic execution
tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(
    callback=calculator1_runner,
    callback_time=500
).start()
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing
I did not use `IOLoop.current().run_in_executor`
I did this instead
```def calculator1_runner():
    """This function is for calling the calculator1 function"""
   Thread(target=calculator1).start()```